# Ckeditor not Validated, using jquery validate, in form wizard setup

Tags: jquery, validation, ckeditor5

my Validation Wizard Form work Good but when i Add Ckeditor class my form validation not work properly, Finished Button not submit form Data.
if i use simple textarea then my form's finish button work properly when i used ckeditor finish button stop working, all other field works good but textarea with ckeditor class not working,

```
<form id="form" action="#" class="wizard-big">
                            <h1>Product Info</h1>
                            <fieldset>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">


                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Product Name</label>
                                            <input id="product_name" name="product_name" type="text" class="form-control" required="">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="qnt">Product Quantity</label>
                                            <input id="qnt" name="qnt" required="" type="text" class="form-control ">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="price">Product Price</label>
                                            <input id="price"  name="price" type="text" class="form-control ">
                                        </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </fieldset>
                            <h1>Product SEO</h1>
                            <fieldset>
                                <h2>Profile Information</h2>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Meta Title</label>
                                            <input id="meta_title" name="meta_title" type="text" class="form-control" required="">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Meta Description</label>
                                            <input id="meta_des" name="meta_des" type="text" class="form-control" required="">
                                        </div>

                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </fieldset>

                            <h1>Product Details</h1>
                            <fieldset>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="editor">Description</label>
                                        <textarea name="editor" id="ckeditor" class="form-control" rows="16" required=""></textarea>
                                    </div>

                            </fieldset>

                            <h1>Finish</h1>
                            <fieldset>
                                <h2>Terms and Conditions</h2>
                                <input id="acceptTerms" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> <label for="acceptTerms">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

This is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#wizard").steps();
            $("#form").steps({
                ignore: [],
                bodyTag: "fieldset",
                onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
                {
                    // Always allow going backward even if the current step contains invalid fields!
                    if (currentIndex > newIndex)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

                    // Forbid suppressing "Warning" step if the user is to young
                    if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age").val()) < 18)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    var form = $(this);

                    // Clean up if user went backward before
                    if (currentIndex < newIndex)
                    {
                        // To remove error styles
                        $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error", form).remove();
                        $(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error", form).removeClass("error");
                    }

                    // Disable validation on fields that are disabled or hidden.
                    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden:not(.cktext)";

                    // Start validation; Prevent going forward if false
                    return form.valid();
                },
                onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
                {
                    // Suppress (skip) "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
                    if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age").val()) >= 18)
                    {
                        $(this).steps("next");
                    }

                    // Suppress (skip) "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
                    if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3)
                    {
                        $(this).steps("previous");
                    }
                },
                onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
                {
                    var form = $(this);

                    // Disable validation on fields that are disabled.
                    // At this point it's recommended to do an overall check (mean ignoring only disabled fields)
                    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";

                    // Start validation; Prevent form submission if false
                    return form.valid();
                    form.validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },

});
                },
                onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
                {
                    var form = $(this);

                    // Submit form input
                    form.submit();
                }
            }).validate({

                        errorPlacement: function (error, element)

                        {

                            element.before(error);
                        }



                    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it by simple method

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#wizard").steps();
     $("#form").steps({
          var messageLength = CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getData().replace(/<[^>]*>/gi, '').length;
          if( !messageLength ) {
              alert( 'Please enter a message' );
              e.preventDefault();
            }
            else 
           {
              //do your stuff
           }
         });
    });
```

Comment: Custom Validation not work on it because of $("#form").steps({}) i show my code above any method to add custom code in to my code, example with my code please

Comment: @ShoaibKhanTareen check my solution